# Divide a circle into n number of equal pixels in Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, math, pixel, projection

Question background: In python, I am working on a task in which I have to project the nodes of geometry (X and Y coordinates). I have plotted a graph which shows Geometry and a circle around the geometry as shown in picture below using below code.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, patches
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [9.00, 6.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
# other plt.scatter or plt.plot here
plt.scatter(x_new, y_new)                             # x_new and y_new is a list of coordinates
circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=4, fill = False)  # (0, 0) is a centre of circle with radius 4
ax.add_patch(circle1)
ax.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

My Question: I have to divide the circle into 36 pixels. I do not have clue at the moment what code I should write to do this. I want my result like in the picture below. Kindly help me on this.

[image]

Comment: There are points inside your disk. Do you want to divide the disk into 36 shares of equal area, or 36 shares that each contain the same number of points?

Comment: If you want to divide the disk into shares of equal area, what has that got to do with the points inside? Please only show things relevant to the question. If the question is not related to the points, then don't show the points.